# Can i start applet via Java Web Start in Appletviewer?

Tags: java, html, applet, java-web-start, appletviewer

In the last week I worked with Java Web Start. I can successfully start applications and applets with JWS. But for one project I have to determine how to start multiple applets via JWS, which should not open in browser but in appletviewer.

My searches always came to one result: Appletviewer can only be started over command line. Is that right? Is there no possibility to give an instruction in my HTML page or something like that, which would bring the applet to be started with the appletviewer?

#### Edit:

Ok, for all those who could search for this in future:
Appletviewer is only for development purposes and the only way to start it **is** the command line command:

```
appletviewer myAppletSite.html
```

But if you really want to start it automatically, you could write an java application to run this system command:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("appletviewer myAppletSite.html");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My searches always came to one result: Appletviewer can only be startet over commandline. Is that right?

No!  In fact, if you launch an applet *non embedded* using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info), the JWS client will use the applet viewer to display it.